# Questions set as resource to learn programming futures, promises and actors

Tags: java, scala, actor, promise, future

I found the "[99 Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/)" very useful to learn Scala Collections and Data Structures. Is there some question bank similar to that which I could use to sharpen my futures/promises skills (and scala specifically, the actors )? Though I am trying to learn Scala, such a problem-and-program resource in other other languages (Java, Haskell, JavaScript) will be also welcome... even a book for that matter...

Comment: closing as off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great resource for java.

http://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/